# Writing a program for Rock paper scissors in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, function

Still new to this so I'm having a little trouble. Who ever can guide me in the right direction, it would be great. This is the code that I have so far:

```
int Rock = 0;
int Paper = 1;
int Scissors = 2;


int PlayerChoice (int PlayerC){
    NSLog(@"Player chooses %i", Rock || Paper || Scissors);
    return 0;
}

int ComputerChoice (int rockpaperscissors){
    return arc4random_uniform(2);
    NSLog(@"Computer chooses ");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    `@autoreleasepool
    {
         PlayerChoice(0);
         ComputerChoice(arc4random_uniform(2));`
    }

    return 0;

}
```

So I don't really know what to do next. I'm trying to call my functions to return a value for the Players choice (either 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 or scissors) and to generate a random number for the computers choice. After that I was going to do a bunch of if statements to compare the two values. Help?

Comment: Haven't got very far have you?  Those `int`s at the top want to be `enum` and I don't understand the use of `||` in the `NSLog()` statement...

Comment: You may need less if-statements as you think: Each option wins against exactly one other option. Everything else is a draw.

Comment: By the way that's almost not Objective-C. The only Objective-C constructs used are `autoreleasepool` and the `NSString` literals.

Comment: Did you try my solution??

Comment: Yeah hasan, it did! Why is the value 3 in the arc4random? Is it counting 0 as its own value?

Answer (score 0):

```
int Rock = 0;
int Paper = 1;
int Scissors = 2;


int PlayerChoice (){
    int i = arc4random_uniform(3);
    NSLog(@"Player chooses %i", i);
    return i;
}

int ComputerChoice (){
    int i = arc4random_uniform(3);
    NSLog(@"Computer chooses %i", i);
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        int p = PlayerChoice();
        int c = ComputerChoice();

        if (p==c)
            NSLog(@"Draw.");
        else
            if ((p==Rock&&c==Scissors)||(p==Scissors&&c==Paper)||(p==Paper&&c==Rock))
                NSLog(@"Player Won.");
            else
                NSLog(@"Computer Won.");
    }

    return 0;

}
```